# $this->getChildHtml('totals') returns empty

Tags: cart, shopping-cart

In `/template/checkout/cart.phtml` the code `$this->getChildHtml('totals')` returns nothing.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks,
Klevis

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your checkout.xml?

```
<block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
```

If not, that could be the reason.

Comment: Yes, I have the exact same thing in checkout.xml. This is inside <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">